# Android Sensors: Compass

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, compass

I'm currently working on a little compass app. So far so good, I got the compass working. I'm using the `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, since the result is much more stable than using `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` combined with `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`. That's my code to calculate the azimuth:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, sensorEvent.values );
// original values are within [-180,180]
azimuth = (float) (Math.toDegrees(SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation)[0]) + 360) % 360;
```

If the device is laying flat on the table, the results are correct. If I lift my phone, so it's standing (the screen is facing to me now), I get incorrect results. I guess that's because my axes changed. How can i properly detect and handle this?

Answer (score 0):

So as many code snippets and threads here suggests, we need some remapping of axis..

```
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remapped);
```

If I do this, the tilt won't influence the azimuth anymore. BUT, the pitch (lifting left or right side of the phone) will change the azimuth and I can't really figure out why.